# Internet Connection Sharing not working on Windows10

Tags: networking, internet, connection-sharing, ics

I cannot share the internet connection between two PCs using ICS. Here is my setup:

- PC 1 is the ICS host. It has internet acces through Wifi.
- Both PC are connected to a switch by Ethernet cables.
- The switch does not have internet access.

On PC1 I enabled sharing through Network connection properties.

[image]

This is what i get on PC1:

[image]

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.24
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

And this on PC2:

[image]
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

PC2 reports no internet connection. Both network adapter are labeled as unknown network instead of "VIRGIN002".

Shouldn't the PC2 have an IP address in the range 192.168.137.X for it to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting a static IP address for PC2 (192.168.137.3)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, does anyone know how to get DHCP assigned addresses on the client PCs without installing 3rd party software?

Windows ICS is supposed to do it's own assigning of DHCP addresses but it doesn't work and setting static IPs on the clients do work but how can we get DHCP to work instead?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207815)